# A bird's-eye view of sending batches of ~10 000 emails per day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4 app running on Heroku.

I need the app to send out about 10 000 emails every morning.

I'm planning to use a service like Mandrill/Sendgrid.

What technical steps should be in place for the above scenario to work reliably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app I work on sends out 100,000s of emails each week. Here are a few of the better things I did in the application to support sending such a high volume of emails each day:

- Setup and configure [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org) to handle all emails asynchronously. This was hugely important for us.
- Develop an API to receive the web hook/call backs from Mailgun (clicks, opens, etc.)
- Compress my html email content before sending (via the [htmlcompressor](https://github.com/paolochiodi/htmlcompressor) gem) to speed up delivery and all that
- Good exception handling and exception reporting reporting for when (not if) things go wrong.

For us and our application, these few things (Sidekiq, especially) has been a godsend.

Comment: Thank you so much for those notes, this is incredibly helpful.